# The next writing challenge could be yours

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge-proposal

### Welcome to the future writing challenge proposal thread.

This is where you will decide what the next writing challenges will be. The next challenge will take place in March 2022.

#### How does the challenge work?

In order:

1. You will first answer to this OP by suggesting an interesting writing challenge.
2. You will up and down vote the answers in this thread
3. The most voted answer will become the challenge
4. A separate OP will be opened, with the challenge rules and the start and end date
5. You will add your entry and edit it until you are happy with it. Everyone is encouraged to give useful feedback and suggestions on how to improve entries in the comments.

Hopefully this will be an interesting experience and a useful way for all of us to grow and learn as writers. You are also welcome to ask questions on Writing SE about all the hurdles, quirks and doubts that you face while composing your entry or reading others.

#### What constitute a challenge?

Mods correct me here, but I'd say that anything goes. If it is not to the taste of the community it will not get as many votes. Some examples I can think of:

- flash fiction, i.e. very short pieces, down to just a few words
- writing the same scene in prose and poetry
- composing a formal letter to an editor
- writing using words that do not contain a specific letter
- composing a dialogue where each character has a different register
- describing a scene without giving any visual clues, so only using any of the other available senses.

Maybe a way to think of a challenge is to think about writing tasks that you find challenging. The limit is your imagination.

Happy writing!

---

#### List of challenges

- [February 2022 Writing Challenge: Tell a story with a terminal log](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2450/34330)
- [March 2022 Writing Challenge: Writing it again, with a different len](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2459/34330)
- [April 2022 Writing Challenge: Write a mute character](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2463/34330)
- [May 2022 Writing Challenge: Sensory experiences](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2471/34330)
- [June 2022 Writing Challenge: Transformations](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2494/34330)
- [July 2022 Writing Challenge: Sharing Secrets, Coming Out, Spilling the Tea](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2503/34330)
- [August 2022 Writing Challenge: Weatherwise](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2513/34330)
- [September 2022 Writing Challenge: Conversation with themself](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2523/34330)
- [October 2022 Writing Challenge: Revenge](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2529/34330)
- [November 2022 Writing Challenge: Death of the protagonist](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2534/34330)
- [December 2022 Writing Challenge: Talking with the prisoner](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2538/34330)
- [January 2023 Writing Challenge: Ironic Contrast](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2544/34330)
- [February 2023 Writing Challenge: Killing for a cause](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2555/34330)
- [March 2023 Writing Challenge: Science Fantasy](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2562/34330)
- [April 2023 Writing Challenge: A fighter against the rebellion](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2565/34330)
- [May 2023 Writing Challenge: Secret Specialized Knowledge](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2572/34330)
- [June–July 2023 Writing Challenge: Voices of Protest](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2577/34330)
- [August 2023 Writing Challenge: Introduce yourself](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2582/34330)

Comment: To keep things clean, I'm deleting used challenges.

Answer (score 2):

### Same events from two (or more) viewpoints

Tell a story twice: covering the same events but from the viewpoints of two different characters. You could experiment with how different you can make their perspectives, but also how similarly some parts can be described to keep the connection between the two parts of the story. If you want to use more than two characters, knock yourself out - go crazy, use as many different viewpoints as you want.

Comment: Inspired by [Writing it again, with a different len(gth)](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2459/28912)

Answer (score -1):

Write a passage in which the point of view character is referred to no more than once per two hundred words.  Less is fine.

Comment: Why downvote without explanation?

Answer (score -1):

### Zombies

Be it flesh-crazed animated corpses, [philosophical zombies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_zombie), or non-morning people who've yet to get their coffee, your task is to write a story involving zombies.